# Results in single string, need one per line

Tags: powershell, powershell-v5.1

Trying to combine some properties from get-netadaptor with get-netipaddress

tried everything I know but the results of the variable $getnet-name are all on one line

```bsh
${getnet-name} = New-Object psobject -Property @{
Status = $null
AdminStatus = $null
LinkLayerAddress = $null
}

${getnet-name}.Status = (Get-NetAdapter -Physical).Status
${getnet-name}.AdminStatus = (Get-NetAdapter -Physical).AdminStatus
${getnet-name}.LinkLayerAddress = (Get-NetAdapter -Physical).LinkLayerAddress

Get-NetAdapter | Get-NetIPAddress | ft interfacealias , ipaddress , prefixorigin ${getnet-name}.AdminStatus -AutoSize
```

```bsh
PS C:\Users\username> ${getnet-name}

Status                               AdminStatus      LinkLayerAddress                                                            
------                               -----------      ----------------                                                            
{Disconnected, Up, Disconnected, Up} {Up, Up, Up, Up} {14-xF-8A-xC-73-00, 0x-50-B6-xx-F0-EB, 10-x5-30-x1-56-B7, 02-00-xC-4x-4F-50}
```

---

This is where I got stuck with looping

```bsh
${getnet-name} = New-Object psobject -Property @{
Status = $null
AdminStatus = $null
LinkLayerAddress = $null
}

${getnet-name}.Status = (Get-NetAdapter).Status
${getnet-name}.AdminStatus = (Get-NetAdapter).AdminStatus
${getnet-name}.LinkLayerAddress = (Get-NetAdapter).LinkLayerAddress

${getnet-obj} = Get-NetAdapter -Physical | Select-Object -Property {${getnet-name}.AdminStatus} , {${getnet-name}.Status} , {${getnet-name}.LinkLayerAddress}

$getnetobj = Get-NetAdapter -Physical

foreach ($InterfaceIndex in $getnetobj) 
{
Get-NetIPAddress | ft interfacealias , ipaddress , prefixorigin , {${getnet-name}.AdminStatus} , {${getnet-name}.Status} , {${getnet-name}.LinkLayerAddress} -AutoSize
}
```

it repeats the same result per interface

---

hoping to eventually get this to also filter for IPv4 addresses only using the Get -AddressFamily filter

---

Currently working, but this really might not be a good way of doing this.  Alternative solutions that are more elegant would be helpful if you would like to add them!

```bsh
$results = @()

foreach ($adapter in (Get-NetAdapter -Physical))
{
    $ipaddresses = $adapter | Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4

    foreach ($ipaddress in $ipaddresses)
    {
        #build the object for reach record you want
        $netadapteraddress = New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Status = $null
        AdminStatus = $null
        LinkLayerAddress = $null
        InterfaceAlias = $null
        IPAddress = $null
        PrefixOrigin = $null
        }

        #properties for the adapter
        $netadapteraddress.Status = $adapter.Status
        $netadapteraddress.AdminStatus = $adapter.AdminStatus
        $netadapteraddress.LinkLayerAddress = $adapter.LinkLayerAddress

        #properties for the ipaddress
        $netadapteraddress.InterfaceAlias = $ipaddress.InterfaceAlias
        $netadapteraddress.IPAddress = $ipaddress.IPAddress
        $netadapteraddress.PrefixOrigin = $ipaddress.PrefixOrigin

        #add to results
        $results += $netadapteraddress
    }

}

$results | ft -wrap
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to loop over the results of the call to `Get-NetAdapter`. Don't try to get fancy with pipelining if it's giving you trouble and a good, old fashioned `foreach` will solve the problem.

Comment: using a foreach ? any chance you could help me with that?

Comment: Try to implement it yourself. If you have a problem that you can't figure out yourself, ask a question here.

Comment: won't let me repost the equestion as a loop/foreach question because it's a duplicate ... also can't post more than once every 60 minutes ... would make a lot more sense to work on this issue here in the original question

Comment: So [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56743987/edit) this question to update it with your new attempts and keep things going here.

Comment: It's not clear what output you expect. Network IP Addresses are not always directly related to adapters and there will usually be more than one IP address per adapter 127.0.0.1 (loopback) and 192.168.1.20 (DHCP assigned) are two typical addresses for the same adapter.

Comment: I do intend on filtering the output for only IPv4 addresses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a better way, but this is how I would go about it. Loop through all physical adapters, loop through each ipaddress for that adapter, create an object to hold the data you want, populate the data. add object to an array, return the array.

```
$results = @()

foreach ($adapter in (Get-NetAdapter -Physical))
{
    $ipaddresses = $adapter | Get-NetIPAddress

    foreach ($ipaddress in $ipaddresses)
    {
        #build the object for reach record you want
        $netadapteraddress = New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Status = $null
        AdminStatus = $null
        LinkLayerAddress = $null
        InterfaceAlias = $null
        IPAddress = $null
        PrefixOrigin = $null
        }

        #properties for the adapter
        $netadapteraddress.Status = $adapter.Status
        $netadapteraddress.AdminStatus = $adapter.AdminStatus
        $netadapteraddress.LinkLayerAddress = $adapter.LinkLayerAddress

        #properties for the ipaddress
        $netadapteraddress.InterfaceAlias = $ipaddress.InterfaceAlias
        $netadapteraddress.IPAddress = $ipaddress.IPAddress
        $netadapteraddress.PrefixOrigin = $ipaddress.PrefixOrigin

        #add to results
        $results += $netadapteraddress
    }

}

$results | format-table -AutoSize
```

Comment: Good attempt an an answer, I just have a few pointers. Since you have `$adapter` defined you can just loop through the `Get-NetIPAddress` results, and add the properties of `$adapter` to the results that you want and capture it all in `$results` directly. Something like: `$Results=ForEach($adapter in (Get-NetAdapter -Physical)){$adapter | Get-NetIPAddress | ForEach-Object{$_ | Add-Member 'Status' $adapter.Status; $_ | Add-Member 'AdminStatus' $adapter.adminstatus; $_ | Add-Member 'LinkLayerAddress' $adapter.linklayeraddress -PassThru}}`

Comment: $RESULTS | ft *
seems to be the right output, thanks for that, it's helping me get there!

Comment: Yeah, I missed the 'copy' from my code. Edited. If this was a correct answer for your question, please mark it as so.

Comment: question - how do you know what properties are available, like you used here:
foreach ($ipaddress in $ipaddresses)
the $ipaddress variable, how did you know you could select off that, based off the properties one could find in get-member?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Get-member ($ipaddress | gm) is an easy way to find properties. also, getting one instance of an object and the type dot, then tab and see what is available.